# Bash script to set Chrome as default for projects only?

Tags: bash, google-chrome, default-browser

Anyone know a way to set up Google Chrome so we can open development servers on? Instead of setting it as the general default browser?

In other words, I don't want my development servers to open up on Safari (that's what I have at the moment) each time I run my local development server, but I don't know how not to do that unless I switch Chrome to be my default browser (which I don't want it to be my default). Is there a way I can write in my `.bash_profile` to do this (automate the process of only opening Chrome for development purposes)?

Comment: How would you differentiate between *normal use* (?) and *specifically for development projects*? You either execute Chrome or you don't.

Comment: Best thing I can think of, create another account on your PC/MacOS specifically for development and set Chrome on it as default.

Comment: "normal" meaning a default browser as we know it to be. But is there a way we can set up Chrome **not** as a default browser but only for development projects (so any development servers we run are opened up in Chrome rather than Safari (which is my default browser at the moment)?

Comment: "so any development servers we run **are opened up** in Chrome rather than Safari "
. Something will *open them up* ( being your IDE for sure ). Just configure it to open Chrome. While the OS uses another browser as default.

Comment: Ahh thanks! I will check out that option.